# CURLOPT_USERPWD to Url

Tags: php, curl, post

I want to know that is it possible to write

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, trim($usrNameLogin) . ":" . trim($usrPwdLogin))
```

in URL, as i want to post this in url for testing via web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put the username and password before the server name in the URL:

```
$url = "https://" . trim($usrNameLogin) . ":" . trim($usrPwdLogin) . "@www.example.com/path/to/file";
```